# Migrate SSIS dtsx to data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am new to data factory.

Data Factory v2 just released new Control flows and Data flows that resemble the workings of SSIS.

Is there a way to migrate your existing SSIS dtsx file to a data factory pipeline ?

Comment: Well this feature is still in preview as at today, but look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now easily lift your existing SSIS packages into the cloud using new managed SSIS hosting capabilities in Data Factory.  You can do that by provisioning an Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime (IR), and then deploy your SSIS package against the Azure-SSIS IR using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) or SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure#deploy-ssis-packages to get started today.